Is Premiere Pro's gaussian blur forensically secure?
I edit a lot of videos with Premiere Pro. I make a lot of tutorials about coding on YouTube, TikTok, Instagram, etc... Some of my tutorials involve a step where I get an API key from a subscription service and incorporate the API into my code. I've been using gaussian blur to obscure my API keys. I create a rectangle shape for the blur and place it over the API key. I always delete the API key after editing the video but I still don't like the idea of my API key being out there. I never know if the company might be re-using the keys or something weird like that. I know it's highly unlikely, but none-the-less, is Premiere Pro's gaussian blur feature resistant to any known type of video recovery? This is where the feature is located:

I also turn up the bur pretty high. In this example, I cranked the blurriness all the way up to 422:

If my blurring method isn't forensically secure, is there another way to obfuscate sections of the video in a way that is forensically secure and can't be recovered?

I don't know whether it is forensically secure. I wouldn't assume it is, if you're blocking sensitive information. Better to match the colour of the background and place a solid colour block to hide your data.
See this from 2007 - even before using AI - this is about pixelation, but the principle is similar:
https://dheera.net/posts/20140725-why-you-should-never-use-pixelation/
See this more recently on Photo Stack Exchange:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35097/is-it-possible-to-re-focus-recover-an-intentionally-blurred-image
